# How to replace VertexLabels in NearestNeighborGraph[] with a tailor-made vertex names

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request

Vertex names in `NearestNeighborGraph[]` are coordinates of undirected graph. I like to replace the vertex names with my own list `vlist`. Furthermore, I like to have two undirected graphs by using both the random list and the normalized values of this random list.

I really tried many different things but could not get what I want.

```
SeedRandom[0];
vlist = {ARG, AUS, AUT, BEL, BGR, BRA, BRN, CAN, CHE, CHL};
g = NearestNeighborGraph[RandomReal[{0, 5}, {10, 2}], 2, 
    VertexLabels -> "Name"]
VertexList[g]
g /. Thread[VertexList[g] -> vlist]
```

**EDIT 1**
As indicated by @Szabolcs, the following does what I want; however, the way I did, shown below, is inconvenient because a graph needs to be created before replacing the tailor-made vertex labels. I want to replace the `vlist` within `NearestNeighborGrap[...]` not after it.

```
SeedRandom[0];
vlist = {"ARG", "AUS", "AUT", "BEL", "BGR", "BRA", "BRN", "CAN", "CHE", "CHL"};
g = NearestNeighborGraph[RandomReal[{0, 5}, {10, 2}], 2]
Graph[g, VertexLabels -> Thread[VertexList[g] -> vlist]]
```

Comment: You need to use the VertexLabels option as described in the documentation. `VertexLanbels -> {v1 -> "label1", v2 -> "labe2", ...}`

Comment: @Szabolcs: I edited the question and you might have an idea how to insert `vlist` into `NearestNeighborGrap[]`.

Comment: Have you tried `verts = RandomReal[{0, 5}, {10, 2}];
NearestNeighborGraph[verts, 2, VertexLabels -> Thread[verts -> vlist]]` ?

Comment: @LouisB: Yes, it works. The answer by @kglr is what I was after because vertex labels are an integral part of `NearestNeighbor Graph[]`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[0]
NearestNeighborGraph[RandomReal[{0, 5}, {10, 2}], 2, 
 VertexLabels -> {_ :> Last[vlist = RotateLeft[vlist]]}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Alternatively,

```
SeedRandom[0]
NearestNeighborGraph[vl = RandomReal[{0, 5}, {10, 2}], 2, 
 VertexLabels -> Thread[vl -> vlist]]
```

> same picture

and

```
SeedRandom[0]
Block[{i = 1}, 
 NearestNeighborGraph[RandomReal[{0, 5}, {10, 2}], 2, 
  VertexLabels -> {_ :> vlist[[i++]]}]]
```

> same picture

Comment: Yes, this was what I was thinking of. Thanks.